# Evaluate $\int _c (x^2-y^2+2ixy)dz$ where c is the circle $\vert z \vert =2$?

Tags: calculus, complex-integration

The question has been deduced to 
$$\int _c  (x^2-y^2+2ixy)dz$$
$$\int _c (x+iy)^2dz$$
$$\int_c  z ^2 dz$$

Now the problem is how to proceed and equate it to the conditions given?

Comment: Also $(x +iy)^2$ = $z^2$, which is holomorphic. And $\{|z| = 2\}$ is a closed curve ;)

Comment: @Hermès are you implying that the question is wrong, because there is a possibility.

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime He is talking about Cauchy integral theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z \mapsto z^2$ is holomorphic and **the path considered is closed, therefore the integral must be zero**. Indeed, one has the following non-trivial theorem:

> **Cauchy's integral theorem :** Let $U$ be an open subset of $\bf C$, and let ${f: U \rightarrow \bf C} $ be holomorphic. Then for any closed rectifiable curve ${\gamma}$ in $U$ that is contractible in ${U}$ to a point, one has $\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 0$.

Otherwise, you could compute the line integral, bringing back the problem to a simple real-integration:

\begin{align*}
\int_{|z| = 2} z^2 dz := \int_{0}^1 (2e^{it2\pi})^2\cdot \frac{\text{d}(2e^{it2\pi})}{\text{d}t} \text{d}t = \dots = 0
\end{align*}